# align axis with \tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following the answer of @Jake to the question [\addplot and \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128162/addplot-and-draw), I set up the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\def\points{
  (1, 1)
  (2, 2)
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, color=red](1, 1) -- (2, 2);
  \begin{axis}[anchor = origin, x = 1cm, y = 1cm, hide axis]
    \addplot [color = blue] coordinates {\points};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Obviously the `axis` and `\tikzpicture` are not properly aligned. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `xmin=0, ymin=0` fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\def\points{
  (1, 1)
  (2, 2)
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, color=red](1, 1) -- (2, 2);
  \begin{axis}[anchor = origin, x = 1cm, y = 1cm, hide axis, xmin=0, ymin=0]
    \addplot [color = blue] coordinates {\points};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]